# Embed fonts in one piece of text, not all of it

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, itext

I want to convert this pdf to pdf/a,but it contains some fonts are not embedded into this file.

The follow picture shows my pdf need embed this fonts.
[image: adobe acrobat font properties screenshot]

so I want to embed no-embedded font in a existing pdf using iText after find this example ([embedfontpostfacto.java](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-5-legacy/chapter-16-pdf-streams#607-embedfontpostfacto.java))

its my test code:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfNumber;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfObject;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;


public class EmbedFontPostFacto {

    /** The first resulting PDF file. */
    public static String RESULT1 = "C:\\Users\\74093\\Desktop\\pdf_\\1000027661706311.pdf";
    /** The second resulting PDF file. */
    public static String RESULT2 = "C:\\Users\\74093\\Desktop\\with_font.pdf";
    /** A special font. */
    public static String FONTPATH = "C:\\Users\\74093\\Desktop\\fonts\\";

    private PdfStream getStream(String fontname) throws IOException {
        // reads font file into byte array
        // the font file
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(FONTPATH+fontname, "r");
        byte fontfile[] = new byte[(int) raf.length()];
        raf.readFully(fontfile);
        raf.close();

        // create PDF stream
        // create a new stream for the font file
        PdfStream stream = new PdfStream(fontfile);
        stream.flateCompress();
        stream.put(PdfName.LENGTH1, new PdfNumber(fontfile.length));
        return stream;
    }

    /**
     *  Manipulates a PDF file src with the file dest as result
     */
    public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        // create a reader object
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        int n = reader.getXrefSize();

        PdfObject object;
        PdfDictionary font;
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));

        //finds unembedded font
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            object = reader.getPdfObject(i);
            if (object == null || !object.isDictionary())
                continue;

            font = (PdfDictionary) object;

            if (font.get(PdfName.FONTNAME) != null) {
                String fontTemp = font.get(PdfName.FONTNAME).toString();
                System.out.println("fontTemp = " + fontTemp);
                if (fontTemp.contains("#")) {
                    System.out.println("fontTemp = " + fontTemp);
                    if (fontTemp.equals("/#bf#ac#cc#e5_GB2312")) {
                        fontTemp = "KaiTi_GB2312.ttf";
                    }
                    if (fontTemp.equals("/#b7#bd#d5#fd#ba#da#cc#e5_GBK")) {
                        fontTemp = "FZHTK.TTF";
                    }
                    if (fontTemp.equals("/#b7#bd#d5#fd#cf#b8#b5#c8#cf#df#bc#f2#cc#e5")) {
                        fontTemp = "FZXDXJW.TTF";
                    }
                    PdfStream stream = getStream(fontTemp);
                    PdfIndirectObject objref = stamper.getWriter().addToBody(stream);
                    font.put(PdfName.FONTFILE2, objref.getIndirectReference());
                }

            }

        }

        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        EmbedFontPostFacto example = new EmbedFontPostFacto();
        example.manipulatePdf(RESULT1, RESULT2);
    }

}
```

Original PDF:

[image: origin pdf]

PDF after embedding:

[image: after embed pdf]

does anybody know where I wrong?

Comment: Please share the pdfs for analysis.

Comment: @mkl its the origin pdf file : https://github.com/ZhangTiny1703/Books/blob/master/1000027661706311.pdf

Comment: Can you also share the processed PDF or the fonts you supplied?

Comment: @mkl  The missing font encoding is gbk-euc-h，I found right font，so this issue has been resolved.  Thank you once again。